# Windows azure logging and debugging

Tags: wcf, azure

I created a cloud application that contains a web role for the web application and a Worker role that hosts a WcfService.
The Endpoint of the WcfService is http://localhost:9967/WcfServiceTestService.

I ran the application from visual studio, everything works fine.
I deployed the application on my windows azure account, the web page opens successfully but when I make a wcf call, the below error is generated

```
There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:9967/WcfServiceTestService that could accept the message.
```

Note that the two roles are in the ready state, but I do not know if the WCF service opened successfully or it generates an error, or should i change the endpoint.

Any way, I added some logging using the below.

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Message");
```

But I do not know how to read them, any advise please.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the baseAddress property in the configuration file for your service does not still have 'localhost'

```
   <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
```

Comment: It should be fine to remove it, then it will resolve on the relative path based on your website configuration.